# argumentnullexception was unhandled insert into

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I'm attempting to insert data to a database via datagridview. My code so far checks to see if a table exists, if not it creates a new table, and then copies the data into it. I can copy the data to the table and all works well. Until I get the error **argumentnullexception was unhandled**. The data is inserted into the table, and I can view the table and see the data is there. This is the description from the error:

> Parameterized query 'insert into [alalala_Thomas_Humphries_Quote]([Item Name], [Item Description], [Retail Price], [Supplier Number], [Quantity Required], [In stock], [Cost Price], [Total Cost],[Total Retail]) values (@item, @desc,@retail,@supplier,@quantity,@stock,@cost,@totalcost, @totalretail)' expects a parameter value which was not supplied.
>   Parameter name: @item

and this is my code:

```
private void insertData()
        {
            string tableName = quotenameTxt.Text + "_" + firstTxt.Text + "_" + surenameTxt.Text + "_Quote";

            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf");
            con.Open();
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 0; i++)
            {
                string query = "insert into [" + tableName + "]([Item Name], [Item Description], [Retail Price], [Supplier Number], [Quantity Required], [In stock], [Cost Price], [Total Cost],[Total Retail]) values (@item, @desc,@retail,@supplier,@quantity,@stock,@cost,@totalcost, @totalretail)";
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@item", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@desc", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@retail", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@supplier", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@quantity", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@stock", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@cost", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@totalcost", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@totalretail", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value));
                da.InsertCommand = cmd;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Quotation :" + tableName + " saved.", "Saved");
            }


        }
```

> I'm using C# 2010 and SQLCe 3.5.

Comment: Can you paste your table creation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data was inserted into the table maybe there is a casting problem from an object after the data is passed into the database.  Try converting your dataGridView1 values to the proper type before you pass them as parameters like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@item", Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)));
```

I hope this helps.